# Where is the "Local Coordinates" option for Inflow Object?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

I want to use an animated object to determine where liquid pours out from, but I cannot for the life of me find the option that dictates this...

Previously this option was in Blender 2.79

So far, after several days of looking, my search efforts have gone in vain. Hopefully this question isn't too redundant!

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use **Source** and **Normal** settings, *Local Coordinates* are a bit useless.

Inflow usually emits fluid only from one direction, there is no specific reason to use whole surface of object as inflow.

It means you can use a disk with same efficiency.

[image]

Originally taken from https://blenderartists.org/t/lets-talk-about-mantaflow/644346/908?u=vklidu